# Can't grab foreign key during after_create callback because it doesn't exist yet!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations, foreign-keys, after-create

I have some models all linked together in memory (parent:child:child:child) and saved at the same time by saving the top-most parent.  This works fine.

I'd like to tap into the after_create callback of one of the children to populate a changelog table.  One of the attributes I need to copy/push into the changelog table is the child's foreign_key to it's direct parent, but it doesn't exist at the time after_create fires!?!

Without the after_create callback, I can look in the log and see that the child is being saved before it's parent (foreign key blank) then the parent is inserted... then the child is *updated* with the id from the parent.  The child's after_create is firing at the right time, but it happens before Rails has had a chance to update the child with the foreign_key.

Is there any way to force Rails to save such a linkage of models in a certain order?  ie.parent, then child (parent foreign_key exists), then that child's child (again, foreign_key is accessible) etc. ??  If not, how would I have my routine fire after a record is created AND get the foreign_key?

Seems a callback like this would be helpful: after_create_with_foreign_keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I was building all my associated models in memory and relying on Rails to save everything when I saved the top-most parent, I couldn't tap into the after_create callbacks and utilize a foreign key (for a change_log table entry) because of the order in which Rails would save the models.  Everything always ended up connected in the proper way, but sometimes a child record would be saved first, then the parent, then an update to the child record to insert the parent_id would happen.

My solution was to not build my models in memory, abandoning the idea of saving everything in one fell swoop. Instead, I would save the top-most model and then create its child via the after_create of that parent.  That child's after_create would then create its child and so on.  I like this arrangement much better as I have more control over my callbacks in relation to foreign keys.  Lastly, the whole thing was wrapped in a db transaction so as to undo any inserts if something went horribly wrong along the way.  This was my original reason for building everything in memory, so I'd have all my ducks in a row before saving.  Model/db transactions alleviates the worry.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `after_update` to catch the child after the parent_id is available?  When `after_update` fires, the parent_id will be available, so if the child is not in the table, insert it.